# Remove timestamp from date in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using this to snag a date value for cells that are created when a spreadsheet updates:

```
setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

But what I get back includes the timestamp (i.e. 10/31/2015 22:16:55), rather than just the date (10/31/2015).

This creates a problem with the logic I'm using that references that cell. The logic is a basic `countif` statements that references date only. I could adjust to deal with `timestamp` but I would rather just not have the `timestamp`. Seems basic but I couldn't find any solution. What am I missing?

Answer (score 14):

The format won't change the fact that the date value is still containing the different times.

To truncate the time from the date value itself try the following:

```
setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: If this helped you can you accept the answer please, so people finding searching through threads can see that a solution was found? Thanks

Comment: @Robin Gertenbach  This answer cause a problem, you are setting a manual formatting "MM/dd/yyyy" USA formatting, this will not work for users in other countries (other locales)!! we need a dynamic formatting such as JAVA DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, local) where "DateFormat.LONG" (style) is decoupled from the locale

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this:

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

example implementation would be something like:

```
// where sheet is a predefined sheet, and getRange is cell F1
sheet.getRange(1,6).setValue(formattedDate).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

For more details Refer [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=es#formatDate(Date,String,String))