# Creating Table in Google App Script With Date Column

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently querying a table from Google sheet which has a Date column. The date column in my dashboard has time info included, which I want to remove; also the starting date in my code is 12/18/2018 but my dashboard starts with one day earlier. 12/17/2018 16.00

My Data source looks like this:

[image]

My Dashboard looks like this:

[image]

My Code Looks like this.

Code.gs:

```html
function doGet(e) {
  
  return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile("Line Chart multiple Table")
  .evaluate()
  .setTitle("Google Spreadsheet Chart")
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  
}

function getSpreadsheetData() {
  
  var ssID  = "1jxWPxxmLHP-eUcVyKAdf5pSMW6_KtBtxZO7s15eAUag";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[1];
  
 
  var data1 = sheet.getRange('A2:F9').getValues();
  var data2 = sheet.getRange('A2:F9').getValues();

  
  var rows   = {data1: data1, data2: data2};

 var r = JSON.stringify(rows);
      return r;
    }
```

Line Chart multiple Table.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="linechartweekly"></div>
  <div id="table2"></div>
 
  <div class = "block" id="message" style="color:red;">
  

  <script>
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
    
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
     
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getSpreadsheetData);
    
     function display_msg(msg) {
          console.log("display_msg():"+msg);
          document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block"; // Style of display
          var div = document.getElementById('message');
          div.innerHTML = msg;
    }

    function getSpreadsheetData() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getSpreadsheetData();
    
    }

    function drawChart(r) {
      // Parse back to an object 
      var rows = JSON.parse(r); 
          
       console.log("rows:"+rows);  

         
      var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows.data1, false);
      
      var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows.data2, false);
    
       
      var options1 = {
        title: 'SPC Chart weekly',
        legend: ['USL', 'UCL', 'Data', 'LCL', 'LSL'],
        colors: ['Red', 'Orange', 'blue', 'Orange', 'Red'],
        pointSize: 4,
      };
            
      var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("linechartweekly"));
      chart1.draw(data1, options1);
     
      var table2 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById("table2"));
      table2.draw(data2, {showRowNumber: false, width: '50%', height: '100%'});   
  
    }
    
    function failure_callback(error) {         
         display_msg("ERROR: " + error.message);
         console.log('failure_callback() entered. WTF'+error.message);
    }
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

May I know how to change my date to the right format removing the time and also ensure the correct starting date

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If I examine the browser console (Control+Shift+J) I see the message 
"Uncaught Error: The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid." if the 3 lines 'commented out' are included.

Also, looking at the example spreadsheet and the code example, the numbers don't make sense; the data starts on row 3, but you seem to be assuming it starts on row 6?

Comment: That's why I commented. What I showed in my data source is just one part of the whole data source. The problem is in my date. When my code is var data3 = sheet.getRange('J2:O9').getValues();
There is no issues. But when I change to var data3 = sheet.getRange('I2:O9').getValues(); by including the date column the dashboard messes up

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem has me stumped, but I do have a workaround; see modified code example below, with some additional error handling.

I've extensively tested the server-side function, and from its perspective there is absolutely no difference in the `row` object that is created whether the range starts at column 'I' or 'J'.

The problem manifests itself in the client-side success handler which, when column 'I' is included is essentially passed a null argument, note the whole  object, not just the row.data1 part, is null.

The row object that is being passed from the server to the client is quite complicated (an object with 3 key value pairs, where the values are fairly long arrays). I can't see anything in the [GAS documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) that disallows this: `Legal parameters and return values are JavaScript primitives like a Number, Boolean, String, or null, as well as JavaScript objects and arrays that are composed of primitives, objects and arrays.` So this could be a bug?

The workaround, illustrated in the code examples below is to stringify the object in the server-side function, and then parsing it back to an object in the  client.

---

HTML

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="table1"></div>
  <div id="linechartweekly"></div>
  <div id="table2"></div>

  <div class = "block" id="message" style="color:red;">

  <script>
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getSpreadsheetData);

    function display_msg(msg) {
          console.log("display_msg():"+msg);
          document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block"; // Style of display
          var div = document.getElementById('message');
          div.innerHTML = msg;
    }

    function getSpreadsheetData() {
      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(failure_callback).withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getSpreadsheetData();
    }

    function drawChart(r) {
      // Parse back to an object 
      var rows = JSON.parse(r); 

      console.log("rows:"+rows);  
      var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows.data1, false);    
      var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows.data2, false);     
      var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows.data3, false);

      var options1 = {
        title: 'SPC Chart weekly',
        legend: ['USL', 'UCL', 'Data', 'LCL', 'LSL'],
        colors: ['Red', 'Orange', 'blue', 'Orange', 'Red'],
        pointSize: 4,
      };

      var table1 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById("table1"));
      table1.draw(data1, {showRowNumber: false, width: '50%', height: '100%'});

      var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("linechartweekly"));
      chart1.draw(data2, options1);

      var table2 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById("table2"));
      table2.draw(data3, {showRowNumber: false, width: '50%', height: '100%'});

    }

    function failure_callback(error) {         
         display_msg("ERROR: " + error.message);
         console.log('failure_callback() entered. WTF'+error.message);
    }

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Code

---

```
function doGet(e) {

      return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile("Line Chart multiple Table")
      .evaluate()
      .setTitle("Google Spreadsheet Chart")
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

    }


    function getSpreadsheetData() {

      var ssID  = "1jxWPxxmLHP-eUcVyKAdf5pSMW6_KtBtxZO7s15eAUag";
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0];
      //var firstrow = 6; //11th row
      //var range = sheet.getRange(firstrow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - firstrow + 1, 6);
      //var data1 = range.getValues();

      var d1 = sheet.getRange('A1:B5').getValues();
      var d2 = sheet.getRange('I2:O4').getValues();
      var d3 = sheet.getRange('I2:O4').getValues();
      var rows   = {data1: d1, data2: d2, data3: d3};
      // Stringify the object
      var r = JSON.stringify(rows);
      return r;
    }
```

Comment: @P Burke I modified my code based on your inputs and revised my question. My current output and code can be seen above. I am facing a new issue. The date format based on the conversion you suggested includes time as well. How to remove the time. And the starting date starts 1 day ahead of the date I mentioned in google sheet. Does it have to do with time zone difference?.

Comment: @SaiRam modifying your original question in this way is not how you use Stackoverflow. As this question and answer thread now no longer makes sense to anyone else who might have had your original problem. New problem = new question. 

There are many other questions on formatting date/time, including this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459462/remove-timestamp-from-date-in-google-apps-script that might help.

Timeszones may well be the problem. Go into the spreadsheet (File>>Spreadsheet Settings] and try setting the timezone to GMT, if that fixes the issue then it is timezone related.

Comment: @P Burke Thanks for your advice. Understand that new problem is a new question. I managed to resolve the timezone issue.

Comment: @P Burke As for the formatting of date and time, the solution setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy'); is applicable only to USA as per the comments. My data is a data table extracted from google sheet. Not exactly sure how to plug in this solution into my code.

Comment: coming up with some solution like this. Does it makes sense?.                          
 var data1 = sheet.getRange('A2').getValues();
  var data2 = setValue(new data1(new data1().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
  var data3 = sheet.getRange('B2:F9').getValues();
  var data4 = (combine data 2 and data 3 - to form new data table) - trying to find the syntax.  
   var rows   = {data4: data4};